# How to push html data realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm using laravel and wants to update  if someone perform update operation in back end

*if user A update post A*

Then all other users able to see updated post without reloading the page

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you

Comment: it is obvious what OP asks. OP asks about websockets

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what web sockets were meant for. In pure Laravel, you could [`Broadcasting`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting). There are several other Laravel frameworks for this like https://github.com/orchidsoftware/web-socket or https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket.